# Global messages on product compare list?

Tags: error, messages

What do I have to do to show the global messages on the compare list template? I tried calling

```
$this->initLayoutMessages('catalog/session');
```

in the Mage_Catalog_Product_CompareController::indexAction but this gives me an error that initLayoutMessages is undefined. Just adding

```
<?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
```

is not enough as it seems.

Thanks!

Comment: http://makandracards.com/magento/10723-messages-and-global-messages-blocks

Comment: What exactly on that page? Its not working the way I tried.

Comment: Do you want to know how the global messages are displayed, like alert,confirmation, or warning etc..